# Portability Bug between Windows and Unix of \r\n (CRLF) and \n (LF)?

Tags: windows, unix, portability, line-endings

When i wrote a code for Shell Script in windows platform

```
#!/bin/bash
a=20
b=10
sum=`expr $a + $b`
echo $sum
```

but tried to execute it on UNIX platform it gave me error `'20\r': command not found` because Windows file ends with /r/n while UNIX file ends with /n.

Any Idea how to remove and process such error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dos2unix`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) - "[a] program that converts plain text files in DOS/MAC format to UNIX format" - or a similar command.

Repositories like Git or Hg they have [support for 'line ending normalization'](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/). Using a version control system is great for other reasons too!

If transferring via [S]FTP/SCP (eg. [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/transfer_mode)) specify "TEXT mode" for the transfer the conversion will be done automatically - the newline transcoding is done as part of the copy/transfer process itself.

A number of "advanced" text editors (eg. [x]emacs, [g]vim, sublime, notepad++, and even Visual Studio) can also repair/normalize such files. These editors can also be used to write the file from the start :)